# heatmap error when implementing as.matrix

Tags: r

When I use heatmap function to make heatmap of dataset, I get an error, I tried:

```
df1$family <- substr(as.character(df1$gene_id), 1, nchar(as.character(df1$gene_id))-2)
df01<-df1$family
df01m<-as.matrix(df01)
heatmap(df01m)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in heatmap(df01m): 'x' must be a numeric matrix
Traceback:

1. heatmap(df01m)
2. stop("'x' must be a numeric matrix")
```

The dataset is big, so I cut some of it:

```
structure(list(gene_id = structure(6:11, .Label = c("__alignment_not_unique", 
"__ambiguous", "__no_feature", "__not_aligned", "__too_low_aQual", 
"ENSG00000000005", "ENSG00000000419", "ENSG00000000457", "ENSG00000000460", 
"ENSG00000000938", "ENSG00000000971", "ENSG00000001036", "ENSG00000001084", 
"ENSG00000001167", "ENSG00000001460", "ENSG00000001461", "ENSG00000001497", 
"ENSG00000001561", "ENSG00000001617", "ENSG00000001626", "ENSG00000001629", 
"ENSG00000001630", "ENSG00000001631", "ENSG00000002016", "ENSG00000002079", 
"ENSG00000002330", "ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000002586", "ENSG00000002587", 
"ENSG00000002726", "ENSG00000002745", "ENSG00000002746", "ENSG00000002822", 
"ENSG00000002834", "ENSG00000002919", "ENSG00000002933", "ENSG00000003056", 
"ENSG00000003096", "ENSG00000003137", "ENSG00000003147", "ENSG00000003249", 
"ENSG00000003393", "ENSG00000003400", "ENSG00000003402", "ENSG00000003436", 
"ENSG00000003509", "ENSG00000003756", "ENSG00000003987", "ENSG00000003989", 
"ENSG00000004059", "ENSG00000004139", "ENSG00000004142", "ENSG00000004399", 
"ENSG00000285989", "ENSG00000285990", "ENSG00000285991", "ENSG00000285992", 
"ENSG00000285993", "ENSG00000285994"), class = "factor"), expr = c(6L, 
754L, 447L, 426L, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

head of the data set:

```
        gene_id         expr
           <fct>       <int>
1   ENSG00000000005     6
2   ENSG00000000419     754
3   ENSG00000000457     447
4   ENSG00000000460     426
5   ENSG00000000938     5
6   ENSG00000000971     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shows that we need a numeric `matrix`.  The `substr` function returns a `character` string.  So, we can convert the `substr`ing `vector` to `numeric`

```
df01m <- as.matrix(as.numeric(df01))
```

Another issue is that `heatmap` requires a `matrix` with atleast 2 rows/2 columns.  Here the `as.matrix` converts the `vector` to a single column `matrix` and it may not work

Comment: I get this error `Warning message in as.matrix(as.numeric(df01)):
“NAs introduced by coercion”` @akrun, I will update the question with data set.

Comment: @user432797 that happens when there are non-numeric elements i.e. `as.numeric(c('1', '3', 'hello'))`

Comment: I used this line to remove non numeric `df<-rp.1a[!grepl("__", df$gene_id),]` @akrun, but it seems that it is not working. What should I do?

Comment: should I convert gene_id to integer? does this help?

Comment: @user432797 the heatmap needs a numeric matrix.  If the `gene_id` is the first column, convert the data.frame to `matrix` with `gene_id` as the rownames

Comment: @user432797 i checked your new updated data.  THe `substr` is returning `substr(as.character(df1$gene_id), 1, nchar(as.character(df1$gene_id))-2)
[1] "ENSG000000000" "ENSG000000004" "ENSG000000004" "ENSG000000004" "ENSG000000009" "ENSG000000009"`

Comment: Can you @akrun suggest your work around this in your answer? that would be a great help

Comment: @user432797 you could use `geom_tile` from `ggplot`, but it requires one more column i.e. `ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = gene_id, expr )) + geom_tile()`

Comment: I tried it @akrun, but I need to compare only two genes, that's why I generated two separate families and compared between them. Now the hurdle how apply heatmap and on this comparison, because when I use `ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = gene_id, expr )) + geom_tile()` it counts all genes! and the heatmap looks black empty plot!

Comment: @user432797 you can use the `fill` as the second column

Comment: @user432797 i meant `library(stringr); df1 %>% mutate(family =  str_remove(gene_id, '..$')) %>% ggplot(aes(gene_id, expr, fill = family)) + geom_tile()`

Comment: is there away to upload my data set file? @akrun

Comment: @user432797 you could upload in github and specify the link

Comment: I just uploaded the file: https://github.com/learnseq/learning/blob/main/RNASeq_post-processing%20(1).csv

Comment: @user432797 with that big dataset, not sure if it needs to be summarised.  I tried `df2 %>% group_by(family = str_remove(gene_id, '..$')) %>% mutate(expr = rescale(expr)) %>% ggplot(aes(gene_id, family)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = expr))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222886/discussion-between-user432797-and-akrun).